# Icinga2 -- host's display_name is ignored by icingaweb2

Tags: ubuntu, icinga

I setup an icinga2 installation to monitor a set of servers. On the client node(ubuntu 16.04, icinga2 installed via apt from the Ubuntu repository) I set in hosts.conf:

```
object Host NodeName {
  /* Import the default host template defined in `templates.conf`. */
  display_name = "Gitlab-CI" 
  import "generic-host"

  /* Specify the address attributes for checks e.g. `ssh` or `http`. */
  address = "127.0.0.1"
  address6 = "::1"

  /* Set custom attribute `os` for hostgroup assignment in `groups.conf`. */
  vars.os = "Linux"
  }
```

But in the web interface I only see its FQDN `gitlabci.example.com`.

Who can I changed the displayed name without removing the `NodeName` directive because this is a nice feature with the standard Ubuntu (and I think all standard Icinga2 setups) configuration?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I still use the FQDN in the webinterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved from the bottom up to the top down configuration mode and updated Icinga2 to version 2.6.0 and then it works as described in the above question.